# refactor nested switch to objects

Tags: java, design-patterns, refactoring

I'd like some advice on refactoring the following method:

```
public boolean makeDecision(String group, int level, int primaryAmount, int secondaryAmount)
{
    if (group.equals("A"))
    {
        switch (level)
        {
            case 0 : return primaryAmount > 10000;break;
            case 1 : return primaryAmount > 20000;break;
            default : return secondaryAmount > 30000; break;
        }
    }
    else if (group.equals("B"))
    {
         switch (level)
         {
              case 0 : return primaryAmount > 40000;break;
              case 1 : return primaryAmount > 50000;break;
              default : return secondaryAmount > 60000; break;
         }

    }
    else if (group.equals("C"))
    {
        switch(level)
        {
            case 0 : return primaryAmount > 70000;break;
            case 1 : return primaryAmount > 80000;break;
            default : return secondaryAmount > 90000; break;
        }

    }
    return false;
}
```

What I'd like to achieve:

- Allow the code to follow the open/closed principle as there will be more groups / levels in time.
- Remove the duplication in the 'level' switch statement.
- Ideally remove the 'group' top level switch statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Groups look like they have behaviour.  You could promote the string group to a first class type. You can also put methods on the class to represent the logic you have got.  I've put daft names on the variables, they could do with much better ones.

```
public class Group {
    public static Group A = new Group(10000,20000,30000);
    public static Group B = new Group(40000,50000,60000);
    public static Group C = new Group(70000,80000,90000);

    private int primaryMin;
    private int primaryMid;
    private int secondaryMax;

    private Group(int min, int mid, int max) {
        primaryMin = min;
        primaryMid = mid;
        secondaryMax = max;
    }

    public boolean getLevel(int level, int primaryAmount, int secondaryAmount) {
       if (level == 0)
         return primaryAmount > primaryMin;
       else if (level == 1) 
         return primaryAmount > primaryMid;
       else 
         return secondaryAmount > secondaryMax;
    }
}
```

So now you can reduce your top level statement down to

```
public boolean makeDecision(Group group, int level, int primaryAmount, int secondaryAmount) {
  return group.getLevel(level, primaryAmount, secondaryAmount);
}
```

You may wish to consider using the [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) to handle an unknown group.

If you say that the levels will grow in time, then I would consider doing almost exactly the same again to introduce the `Level` class and push the if/else chain in there as another layer of polymorpshim.  This would then become the [double dispatch pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch) as first you'd dispatch on the type of `Group` and then on the type of `Level`.  This should mean that you can add new code without needing to modify the existing ones.

Comment: how would i dispatch on the type of group? are you saying the I should have a separate class for each group?

Comment: By dispatch, I just mean call a method on group.  So `group.GetLevel` in the example above.  At the moment, group isn't a class hierarchy because the logic is simple enough to fit in one place.  You could write a different subclass per group, but since they only differ in data and not behaviour, I wouldn't do that yet.  Similarly for Level.  I'd only bother adding new subclasses if they genuinely differ in behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

Since each case is computed by a trivial comparison, you can just as well do all comparisons either way.

So here's a suggestion:

```
boolean[] aSol = { primary > 10000, primary > 20000, secondary > 30000 };
boolean[] bSol = { primary > 40000, primary > 50000, secondary > 60000 };
boolean[] cSol = { primary > 70000, primary > 80000, secondary > 90000 };

level = Math.min(level, 2);
return group.equals("A") ? aSol[level] :
       group.equals("B") ? bSol[level] :
       group.equals("C") ? cSol[level] :
       false;
```

I think it's fairly readable and maintainable.

Here's another slightly different formulation:

```
boolean[][] result = {
        { primary > 10000, primary > 20000, secondary > 30000 },
        { primary > 40000, primary > 50000, secondary > 60000 },
        { primary > 70000, primary > 80000, secondary > 90000 } };

int groupId = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C").indexOf(group);

if (groupId == -1)
    return false;

boolean[] groupResult = result[groupId];
return groupResult[Math.min(level, groupResult.length-1)];
```

Another option is to create an interface with a method

```
makeDecision(int level, int primaryAmount, int secondaryAmount)
```

and then populate a `Map<String, GroupDecision>` with decision procedures,

```
groupMap.put("A", new GroupDecision() { ... });
groupMap.put("B", new GroupDecision() { ... });
groupMap.put("C", new GroupDecision() { ... });
```

and then call

```
return groupMap.get(group).makeDecision(level, primaryAmount, secondaryAmount);
```

This approach is probably the most extendible and readable approach.

Comment: but if i have a new level then aSol, bSol and cSol will all need to be modified?

Comment: Could you clarify your concern? The program needs to be complete right? What solution would allow you to increase the number of possible levels, without requiring change in the code?

Comment: my concern is that if a new level comes along I don't want to modify *existing* code. I want to add *new* code to deal with it so that I can follow the open-closed principle.